# view id is null after changing the language

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.1, MyFaces 2.0.7, Websphere Application Server 7.

I am using **`p:tabView`** component with 3 tabs. When I change the language in **`first tab`** application works fine without any errors. But If I go to **`second or third tab`** -> change the language -> Then navigate to any one of the inactive tabs. I get the following exception.

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Facelet /.xhtml?REQUIRED=false not found at: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/mblade140/installedApps/mblade140/ldapmanager-application-ear.ear/ldapmanager-application-web.war/.xhtml?REQUIRED=false
[08.02.13 12:55:42:349 CET] 00000090 SystemErr     R    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:286)
```

Following is how I have written code for **`p:tabView`** component

```
    <h:form id="headerForm" prependId="false">
    <h:inputHidden id="activeTabIndexId" value="#{AppUserManagementBean.activeTabIndex}" />
    <p:remoteCommand update="tabView:fieldAppUserMgmt,tabView:filterApps,tabView:filterRoles,tabView:panel_grid_newuser" 
            name="onTabChange" 
            process="activeTabIndexId,@this" 
            actionListener="#{AppUserManagementBean.onTabChanged}" >
            <f:param name="REQUIRED" value="false"/>
    </p:remoteCommand>

    <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true" activeIndex="#{AppUserManagementBean.activeTabIndex}"
        onTabChange="document.getElementById('activeTabIndexId').value = index;onTabChange();">

        <p:tab id="userManagementTab" title="#{msgs.UserManagement_Title}">
            <ui:include src="UserManagement.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="applicationUserManagementTab"
            title="#{msgs.AppUserMgmt_Title}">
            <ui:include src="AppUserManagement.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="userGroupManagementTab"
            title="#{msgs.UserGroupMgmt_Title}">
            <ui:include src="UserGroupManagement.xhtml" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Here is the code I written to change the language in backing bean. This method is called on changing the language in **`p:selectOneMenu`**

```
    public void setLocale(String selectedLocale) {
    System.out.println("Changing locale to "+selectedLocale);
    this.locale = selectedLocale;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Locale> entry : countryMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().toString().equals(selectedLocale)) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
                    .setLocale((Locale) entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone shed light on this.

Comment: All that stuff you have in `onTabChange`, why are you not doing it with `<p:ajax/>`?

Comment: that's b'coz, in first tab I have put 4 raido buttons and xhtml pages are loaded using partial rendering. When I move out of first tab to second or third tab, and tried to submit the form in second or third tab, ajax requests in first tab are also processed by JSF. In ideal case JSF should not validate the fields in first tab as it is not active. JSF validations triggered on Input fields in first tab and thus JSF is not allowing to submit the form in second or third tab as validations in first tab are failed.To fix this issue I had to use this workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...

the problem was that for **`p:tabView`** I had set **`dynamic=true`**. I have removed **`dynamic=true`**. Language change option is working now. I dont know why......